# CTR mode of operation in the Bouncy Castle lightweight API?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, bouncycastle

Is there an implementation of CTR (counter) mode of operation in the Java / C# Bouncy Castle lightweight API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.SICBlockCipher`.

The documentation of that class reads:

> Implements the Segmented Integer Counter (SIC) mode on top of a simple block cipher. This mode is also known as CTR mode.

Note that the `SICBlockCipher` class does not seem to implement buffering of large key streams. It does also not provide functionality to encryption / decrypt from a specific offset within the key stream. At least not in versions of the class up to API level 1.51.